# Passing attributes to neighbouring polygons

Tags: polygon, fields-attributes

I have an ecosystem polygon layer that has been updated using a more recent tree cover layer (to remove cleared areas and also to re-align veg boundaries where growth has occured).

Where the polygons have been 'grown out', not all values have been passed along to the new, neighbouring polygon (only the actual RE value itself).  In other words, the existing polygon is in the data, with an adjoining polygon to represent the new area, which should be treated as the same RE unit).

What would be the best approach to re-attribute these polygons?

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: i am using esri and/or fme